# Lorentzian inner product in matrix form using Pytorch

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, matrix-multiplication

I want to compute the Lorentzian inner product, that is <x,y> = -x1y1 + x2y2 + x3y3 +...
I have the code

```
 res = torch.sum(x * y, dim=-1) - 2 * x[..., 0] * y[..., 0]
```

But this fails to work, because I keep getting this error -
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (450) must match the size of tensor b (30) at non-singleton dimension 0

I need the inner product in the matrix form. So I did this -

```
 res = torch.matmul(x,torch.transpose(y,0,1))
-2*torch.matmul(x[...,0],torch.transpose(y[...,0],0,0))
```

But I get a new error
RuntimeError: inconsistent tensor size, expected tensor [450] and src [30] to have the same number of elements, but got 450 and 30 elements respectively.

I have tried this on a simple toy example -

```
x = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3]])
y = torch.tensor([[2, 2, 2]])
prod = torch.matmul(x,torch.transpose(y,0,1))-2*torch.matmul(x[...,0],torch.transpose(y[...,0],0,0))
print(prod)
```

Output : tensor([[8]]) which is right. But somehow doesn't seem to work in the application I am working on.

I am not sure how to solve this. Any insights are welcome please!

Comment: Can you obtain/print the shapes of the input vectors in the real scenario? If so, create a toy example with those shapes. Just add a `print(x.shape, y.shape)` right before the inner product.

Comment: Hi thanks for your input. I did this - import torch
x = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3]])
y = torch.tensor([[2, 2, 2]])
x[...,0] *= -1
res = torch.matmul(x,torch.transpose(y,0,1))
print (res). And my application code started working.

Comment: Nice! feel free to answer your own question with the code that solved it. It might be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

So I did this -

```
import torch
x = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3]])
y = torch.tensor([[2, 2, 2]])
x[...,0] *= -1
res = torch.matmul(x,torch.transpose(y,0,1))
print (res)
```

It started working for my application.